# I am getting size of a list is 0 however it is showing the right count of the items when I am verifying it using x path helper

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find out count of number of items on a page that is Correspondence Courses.All of the items contains same class name. It is returning 0 size all the time however the xpath I am using giving correct cont when I am verifying it using xpath helper. It is my selenium code here:

```
 @Test(priority=2)
 public void AddItems() throws InterruptedException
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("CORRESPONDENCE COURSES")).click();
 List <WebElement> listele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='custom-
 block-grid']/div/ul/div[1]/li"));

 System.out.println(listele.size());
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="small-9 columns product-card left" role="main" id="card-width" style="padding-left: 10px; float: right !important">
  <article>
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 cp-inline-block padding-card ng-scope" ng- repeat="data in testseriesData" style="">
      <li id="custom-block-grid" class="">
        <div class="panel card-background card-shadow">
          <ul class="no-bullet">
            <div class="image-card-container">
              <li class="card-pointer image-align-card" ui-sref="description({cName: 'books', id: data.id})" href="#/books/description/id=750">
                <img ng src="https://d2fldgtygklyv6.cloudfront.net/SSC_Corr_Course_with_test_HINDI_1500195234532.png" class="img-card-dim" src="https://d2fldgtygklyv6.cloudfront.net/SSC_Corr_Course_with_test_HINDI_1500195234532.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <span class="line-clamp card-pointer label-card title-border-top ng-binding" ui-sref="description({cName: 'books', id: data.id})" href="#/books/description/id=750">SSC Correspondence Course (HINDI MEDIUM)</span>
            <div class="price-field">
              <del class="fade ng-binding"><i class="icon-rupee icon-rupee-buy-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>4,499</del>
              <span class="cp-float-right selling-price ng-binding"><i class="icon-rupee icon-rupee-buy-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>3,599</span>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart listing-add-to-cart margin-force-zero sf-button-secondary" ng-click="addToCart(data)" role="button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="icon-cart icon-cart-buy-card"></span>
              <span>ADD TO CART</span>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="small-9 columns product-card left" role="main" id="card-width" style="padding-left: 10px; float: right !important">
  <article>
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 cp-inline-block padding-card ng-scope" ng- repeat="data in testseriesData" style="">
      <li id="custom-block-grid" class="">
        <div class="panel card-background card-shadow">
          <ul class="no-bullet">
            <div class="image-card-container">
              <li class="card-pointer image-align-card" ui-sref="description({cName: 'books', id: data.id})" href="#/books/description/id=750">
                <img ng src="https://d2fldgtygklyv6.cloudfront.net/SSC_Corr_Course_with_test_HINDI_1500195234532.png" class="img-card-dim" src="https://d2fldgtygklyv6.cloudfront.net/SSC_Corr_Course_with_test_HINDI_1500195234532.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <span class="line-clamp card-pointer label-card title-border-top ng-binding" ui-sref="description({cName: 'books', id: data.id})" href="#/books/description/id=750">SSC Correspondence Course (HINDI MEDIUM)</span>
            <div class="price-field">
              <del class="fade ng-binding"><i class="icon-rupee icon-rupee-buy-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>4,499</del>
              <span class="cp-float-right selling-price ng-binding"><i class="icon-rupee icon-rupee-buy-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>3,599</span>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart listing-add-to-cart margin-force-zero sf-button-secondary" ng-click="addToCart(data)" role="button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="icon-cart icon-cart-buy-card"></span>
              <span>ADD TO CART</span>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="small-9 columns product-card left" role="main" id="card-width" style="padding-left: 10px; float: right !important">
  <article>
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 cp-inline-block padding-card ng-scope" ng- repeat="data in testseriesData" style="">
      <li id="custom-block-grid" class="">
        <div class="panel card-background card-shadow">
          <ul class="no-bullet">
            <div class="image-card-container">
              <li class="card-pointer image-align-card" ui-sref="description({cName: 'books', id: data.id})" href="#/books/description/id=750"><img ng src="https://d2fldgtygklyv6.cloudfront.net/SSC_Corr_Course_with_test_HINDI_1500195234532.png" class="img-card-dim" src="https://d2fldgtygklyv6.cloudfront.net/SSC_Corr_Course_with_test_HINDI_1500195234532.png">
              </li>
            </div>
            <span class="line-clamp card-pointer label-card title-border-top ng-binding" ui-sref="description({cName: 'books', id: data.id})" href="#/books/description/id=750">SSC Correspondence Course (HINDI MEDIUM)</span>
            <div class="price-field">
              <del class="fade ng-binding"><i class="icon-rupee icon-rupee-buy-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>4,499</del>
              <span class="cp-float-right selling-price ng-binding"><i class="icon-rupee icon-rupee-buy-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>3,599</span>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart listing-add-to-cart margin-force-zero sf-button-secondary" ng-click="addToCart(data)" role="button" tabindex="0">
              <span class="icon-cart icon-cart-buy-card"></span>
              <span>ADD TO CART</span>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</div>
```

And similarly for other items

Answer (score 1):

If it's working when you test it in the browser but not when your script is running, most likely it's a timing problem. The code runs fast and likely returns 0 before the page has completed loading. The way to solve this issue to add a wait, `WebDriverWait`.

Example code is below. The wait returns the collection of elements waited for so you can then stick that in a `List`, as you did with your code, and then print the `size()` of the collection. I changed the name of the variable to be more descriptive, `courses`, instead of `listele`. It will help you and others read and understand your code more easily.

```
By locator = By.cssSelector("article");
// By locator = By.xpath("//*[@id='custom-block-grid']/div/ul/div[1]/li");
List<WebElement> courses = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
System.out.println(courses.size());
```

Another thing... since you are just counting the number of courses, those are denoted with the `article` tag so you can just count those which makes your locator simple.

Comment: It is working using WebDriver wait.Can we use Thread.sleep() before List <WebElement> listele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='custom-
 block-grid']/div/ul/div[1]/li")); ?

Comment: @Preet Using `Thread.Sleep()` is a bad practice. You can do some googling to see why. `WebDriverWait` is the best practice for waiting.